# How do I move gnome-panel between monitors without gnome-settings-daemon in xmonad?

Tags: xmonad, multi-monitor, gnome-panel

I'm running xmonad with gnome-panel, but not gnome-settings-daemon. I start up gnome-panel by spawning in xmonad.hs. How can I (on the command line) get gnome-panel to switch monitors?

xmonad.hs:

```
myManageHook :: [ManageHook]
myManageHook =
  [ resource =? "Skype" --> doFloat
  , resource =? "Vncviewer" --> doFloat
  , resource =? "gnome-panel" --> doIgnore
  , isFullscreen --> doFullFloat
  ]

startup :: X()
startup = do
  spawn "gnome-panel"

main = xmonad $ ewmh defaultConfig
    { modMask = mod4Mask
    , terminal = "gnome-terminal"

    -- avoidStruts prevents overlap with gnome-panel
    -- smartBorders disables border in full screen (or single-window)
    , layoutHook = avoidStruts $ smartBorders $ layoutHook defaultConfig
    , manageHook = composeAll myManageHook <+> manageHook gnomeConfig

    -- docksEventHook reworks windows whenever a dock gets in the way
    , handleEventHook = docksEventHook
    , startupHook = startup
    }
```